# PHP class not found when using class in another class

Tags: php

I have 2 class in Two sub folders within a mother folder in am trying to auto load classes within index.php file and then use one into another one but not working yet.Take a look at this->

FOLDER STRUCTURE

```
MotherFOlder
  |- lib
  |   |- Api.php
  |- inc
  |   | - SC.php
  |- index.php
```

in index.php i am coding like this:

```
namespace ACX;

use ACX\lib\Api;
use ACX\inc\SC;

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\autoload');

function autoload($class = '') {
    if (!strstr($class, 'ACX')) {
        return;
    }
    $result = str_replace('ACX\\', '', $class);
    $result = str_replace('\\', '/', $result);
    require $result . '.php';
}
```

Then in Api.php

```
<?php
namespace ACX\lib;
class Api{
    private static $instance = null;

    public static function getDataJSON(){

        return 'data';
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }   
}
```

And in SC.php

```
<?php
namespace ACX\inc;

class SC{
    private static $instance = null;


    public static function getDataSets(){
        $data = Api::getDataJSON();
        return $data;
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

But i am getting this error `Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'inc/Api.php'`

Is there any bug in the code?

Comment: Why index.php has a namespace?

Comment: `Api.php` is inside `lib/Api.php` but your error says it's inside `inc/Api.php`. Why? Try to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple because you forgot to import `Api.php` class inside `SC.php` class where you call `Api::getDataJSON()`. As `Api.php` is under this `ACX\lib` namespace, import it as below:

```
<?php

namespace ACX\inc;

use ACX\lib\Api; // This needs to be imported

class SC {

    // other code

    public static function getDataSets(){
        $data = Api::getDataJSON(); // You're calling Api.php class here
        return $data;
    }

    // other code
}
```